# laravel select statement calling sub model using "with" statement

Tags: laravel

When I call a select statement using a with clause calling supplier model I want the supplier class to call the user related model. how do I do that

```
$products = Product::select(['id', 'title', 'slug', 'unit_price',
 'sell_price', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 
'updated_by', 'supplier_id'])->with('supplier');

// when calling supplier model call user model as well

class Supplier extends Model
{
    protected $table = "suppliers";

    protected $fillable = ['company', 'email'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'email', 'email');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) you can perform nested eager loading using the dot notation.

So in you example

```php
...->with('supplier');
```

becomes

```php
...->with('supplier.user');
```